# SQL Server - Find Duplicate entries in a column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please could someone help me in finding a solution for the below example?

[image]

every work carried out by a user (OperatorID) should have IN & OUT, if for an instance the user enter either IN twice or OUT twice in a consecutive rows then I need to take the latest transaction ONLY onto my results.

So, in my above example ID (102) is what we are interesting in and ignoring the rest.

"Location" can be any thing i.e. SI/SO, D1/DO and so on.

Comment: see the link referenced to know more on how to ask a perfect question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: also please avoid posting images,unless necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using [**`exists()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) to get the second row of the duplicate where `id=id-1` and `operatorid` and `location` are the same:

```
select * 
from t
where exists (
  select 1
  from t i
  where i.OperatorId = t.OperatorId 
    and i.id = t.id-1
    and i.Location = t.Location
)
```

returns:

```
+-----+---------------------+----------+------+--------+------------+-------------+-------------------+
| id  |      datetime       | location | site | client | operatorId | containerId |    WorkflowId     |
+-----+---------------------+----------+------+--------+------------+-------------+-------------------+
| 102 | 2017-02-03 11:10:21 | PO       | AA   | TEMP   | Test1      |         451 | 123F-258G-369147C |
+-----+---------------------+----------+------+--------+------------+-------------+-------------------+
```

---

If `Id` is not sequential, you could use a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with **[`row_number()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)**:

```
with t as (
  select *
    , rn = row_number() over (order by id)
  from #temp
)

select * 
from t
where exists (
  select 1
  from t i
  where i.OperatorId = t.OperatorId 
    and i.rn = t.rn-1
    and i.Location = t.Location
)
```

Comment: Sorry SqlZim, for some reason i ma getting blank results, any idea?
I first store the required values in a Temp table, and used your query in the below format. Not sure where I am doing it wrong. could you assist?
select t.*
from #temp1 t
where exists (
  select 1
  from #temp1 i
  where i.OperatorId = t.OperatorId 
    and i.id = t.id-1
    and i.Location = t.Location
)

Comment: @satya is `Id` sequential as it is in your example?

Comment: Found what the issue is on my table itself. the ID wasn't (-1) entry. I believe I can now replicate the same principle and work it out.
Thanks for Help though

Comment: is their a quickest way tp sort if the ID is not sequential? please advise

Comment: @satya Updated my answer

Comment: BINGO... Thanks SqlZim. It worked. it was great help and saved lot of time :)

Comment: I know I may greedy, it worked perfectly fine for few of the data. But when ran for a period of a month, its taking fare amount of time.
any idea please

Comment: when you are selecting into your temp table, include the `row_number()` there and we won't have to create it using the `cte`. also, add an index to your temporary table if there isn't one. `rn` would make a good primary key for the temp table.